Create reservation with agent
We have set up our own reservation database. Now we want to migrate the documents to the Notes resource database.
I have created an agent for this as I have 1000 documents. I create the documents but the room can still be booked. I have to open the document and save it, then it works. In the agent I cannot do this with editdocument because the reservation gets error messages because the scheduler is not set.
What can I do?

You may be able to get the same effect by calling
doc.computwithform(true, true)
You will need to make sure that the “form” item is set to the name of the form you want to compute.

Unfortunately, this is not the solution. I have already tried it and it has even got worse. Now it has lost the room name.

You will need to have a look at what is different between the documents that work and those that don’t.  You may need to go through and manually process these unless you can work out what code is being triggered.
